# Error with SVM hyperparameter tuning in mlrMBO Bayesian optimization

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, mlr

I am trying to optimize an SVM for a classification task, which has worked for many other models I've tried this process on. Yet, when I used an SVM in my model based optimization function it returns an error: "Error in checkStuff(fun, design, learner, control) : Provided learner does not support factor parameters."

Attached is the relevant code. In my training task, all independent variables are numeric, the only factor is my outcome of interest.

```
library(mlr)
library(mlrMBO)
library(dplyr)
library(PRROC)
library(ggplot2)
library(DiceKriging)
traindf <- read.csv("/Users/njr/Google Drive/HMS IR Research/NSQIP Research/Endovascular/randomtraining.csv")
testdf <- read.csv("/Users/njr/Google Drive/HMS IR Research/NSQIP Research/Endovascular/randomtesting.csv")
traindf$Amputation<-as.factor(traindf$Amputation)
testdf$Amputation <- as.factor(testdf$Amputation)
trn.task = makeClassifTask(data = traindf, target = "Amputation", positive = "2")
test.task = makeClassifTask(data = testdf, target = "Amputation", positive = "2")
set.seed(9)
svmlrn =  makeLearner("classif.svm", predict.type = "prob")

svm_model <- mlr::train(svmlrn, task = trn.task)
res = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10, stratify = TRUE)
par5 = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("kernel", values = c("radial", "polynomial", "linear")),
  makeNumericParam("cost", -15, 15, trafo = function(x) 2^x),
  makeNumericParam("gamma", -15, 15, trafo = function(x) 2^x, requires = quote(kernel == "radial")),
  makeIntegerParam("degree", lower = 1, upper = 4, requires = quote(kernel == "polynomial"))
)
mbo.ctrl = makeMBOControl()
mbo.ctrl = setMBOControlInfill(mbo.ctrl, crit = crit.ei)
mbo.ctrl = setMBOControlTermination(mbo.ctrl, iters = 35, max.evals = 25)
design.mat = generateRandomDesign(n = 50, par.set = par5)
surrogate.lrn = makeLearner("regr.km", predict.type = "se")
ctrl = mlr::makeTuneControlMBO(learner = surrogate.lrn, mbo.control = mbo.ctrl, mbo.design = design.mat)

parallelStartMulticore(cpus = 8L)
res.mbo = tuneParams(makeLearner("classif.svm"), trn.task, resampling = res, par.set = par5, control = ctrl, 
                     show.info = TRUE, measures = auc)
parallelStop()
```

this is the traceback error code:

```
6.
stop("Provided learner does not support factor parameters.")
5.
checkStuff(fun, design, learner, control)
4.
initOptProblem(fun = fun, design = design, learner = learner, control = control, show.info = show.info, more.args = more.args)
3.
mlrMBO::mbo(tff, design = control$mbo.design, learner = control$learner, control = mbo.control, show.info = FALSE)
2.
sel.func(learner, task, resampling, measures, par.set, control, opt.path, show.info, resample.fun)
1.
tuneParams(makeLearner("classif.svm"), trn.task, resampling = res, par.set = par5, control = ctrl, show.info = TRUE, measures = auc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your parameter set has a categorical parameter (kernel) and the surrogate model you're using (regr.km) doesn't support that. You could try for example a random forest as surrogate model instead.

Comment: Thank you! I had managed to get it working through random search as well as just letting MBO decide what the learner should be. I totally forgot that DiceKriging is a linear method that doesnt handle categorical inputs.